# Is there a feasible drag gesture solution for a boggle type word grid?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I just would like to know at a high level if there is a non-hack solution for this problem.

Word Grid on phone screen:
[image: Word Grid on phone screen]

I would like for the user to be able to start on a given letter, then drag to other letters to form words. For a developer perspective I care about:

- Is there a way for for each children to know about its neighbors?
- Is the solution here to map every neighboring letter to a x,y coordinate or is there a better solution?

I feel like the answer here involves a geometry reader?

Happy to include more details as needed.

Comment: So the letters are always in this grid pattern, they are only shuffled around by the user's gesturing?

Comment: yes and no. The letters in the grid are pre-determined. I generate that in the view model. As for the gesturing, that is not meant to shuffle any of the letters. The drag gesture is only for the app to determine what sequence of letters the user has chosen. 

(Sorry for the delay, in an area with bad connection)

Comment: Not something with geometry reader but something with path, it wouldn't be "simple" but not hard either.

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for the direction. Any references to get me started?

Comment: Not really it would be pure improvisation. Combine the drag gesture position with a path for the line add line from start to end. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `PreferenceKey`.
You can report the size of the children to those parents by using it.

I recommend you read [SwiftUI Lab's article](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/).